# Nodemailer - how send Uint8Array like picture attachment

Tags: javascript, nodemailer, uint8array

I have picture in "`Uint8arrary`" and I would like to send this in email attachment.

In my js:

```
attachments: [{
    content: fileInfo.fileContent, // Uint8arrary
    filename: 'project',
    encoding: 'binary'
}]
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What does't work? Be more precise.

Comment: In my html template (jade) i have <code>img(src="project")</code> and this not work. I have empty email. How to display my picture?